# Line Ordering Issue with Arabic PDF Text Using Google Cloud Document AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai, google-ai-platform

I have an app that uses Document AI to process PDFs and extract text from it. When I use the stable version but still is not accurate. The processed text seems to have its lines mixed up, not following the original document's order. This issue is critical for my application, as it relies on accurate text extraction for further processing.

I tried to read the file directly instead of send it as buffer and following the quick-start guides Google provided and here is the code I wrote:

```js
  async processDocument(fileContent: Buffer | undefined, contentType: string) {
    try {
      const name = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}/processors/${processorId}`;

      const encodedFile = Buffer.from(fileContent!).toString("base64");

      const request = {
        name,
        rawDocument: {
          content: encodedFile,
          mimeType: contentType,
        },
      };

      const [result] = await this.client.processDocument(request);
      const { document } = result;

      return document;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

[image]

Anyone faced same issue or have idea what could be the problem? In Google cloud console, testing the processor seems to be working fine and returned different response with correct order.

Comment: @KJ I see your point, however when I use the same document with Azure OCR API, I get expected results. Hence, I think the pretrained models in Google Cloud have some bugs when it comes to processing Arabic text. It's great with English text though. Anyway, Thanks for your reply

Comment: Hi @Khaled Saleh, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: @kiranmathew Sounds good. I will create a ticket later with more samples as I collect more.